# Insert in order to an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, insertion

I'm trying to write  a function that inserts into a dictionary (an array of strings), but in alphabetical (lexical) order, but I'm running into an invalid read of size 8 error and I'm not entirely sure why.

Here is my code:

```
int insertWord(char **array, int *count, char word[])
{
    char *wordPtr;

    wordPtr = (char *)malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (wordPtr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"    Malloc of array[%d] failed!\n", *count);
        return -1;
    }
    /* Memory for this word has been allocated, so copy characters
       and insert into array */

    strcpy(wordPtr, word);

    // Iterate through the word array
    // Check if str1 > other strings
    // Lower ascii value = earlier in the alphabet
    // Will return neg value if str1 < str2 (str1 comes before str2)
    // Will return 0 if they are equal
    // Will return pos value if str1 > str2 (str1 comes after str2)
    // Check for an element that comes after the given word in the alphabet
    bool greaterElementFound = false;
    int indexLoc = *count;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < *count ; i ++){
            // If compare is a neg #, that means that wordPtr comes before array[i]
            // So array[i] must be shifted right, and wordPtr must be inserted in its place
            if(strcasecmp(wordPtr, array[i]) < 0){
                    greaterElementFound = true;
                    indexLoc = i;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if(greaterElementFound == true){
            // Account for overwrite of last element
            array[*count+1] = array[*count];
            // Shift all elements over from indexLoc to *count
            for(int i = *count; i > indexLoc; i--){
                    array[i] = array[i-1];
            }
    }
    array[indexLoc] = wordPtr;

    (*count)++;

return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a suppressed error in valgrind :

```
==4123== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
==4123== 
==4123== 2 errors in context 1 of 1:
==4123== Invalid write of size 8
==4123==    at 0x401056: insertWord (in /import/linux/home/jball2/CLab/lab2)
==4123==    by 0x400E3E: loadArray (in /import/linux/home/jball2/CLab/lab2)
==4123==    by 0x400AAE: main (in /import/linux/home/jball2/CLab/lab2)
==4123==  Address 0x51b1450 is 0 bytes after a block of size 400 alloc'd
==4123==    at 0x4C2779D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4123==    by 0x400D91: loadArray (in /import/linux/home/jball2/CLab/lab2)
==4123==    by 0x400AAE: main (in /import/linux/home/jball2/CLab/lab2)
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

-------------------------------------FOR REFERENCE-------------------------------------------

Here is my loadArray() function:

```
int loadArray(char *inFileName, char ***array, int *count, int *capacity)
{
FILE *inFile;
char word[WORD_LENGTH];  /* this is the ONLY auto array we'll need */

if ((inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error opening input file, %s\n", inFileName);
    return -1;
}

*array = (char **)malloc(*capacity * sizeof(char*));
if (*array == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc of array in loadArray failed!\n");
    return -1;
}

printf("Reading file %s (each . is 5000 words read)\n", inFileName);

*count = 0;
while (fscanf(inFile, "%s", word) == 1)
{
    if (*count >= *capacity)
    {
    /* call a function that will double the size of the array and copy its contents */
    doubleArray(array, count, capacity);
    }

    if (insertWord(*array, count, word) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"    Insert returned an error!\n");
        fclose(inFile);
        return 1;
    }

    if (*count % 5000 == 0)
    {
        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);  /* stdout is buffered, so have to force flush */
    }
}

fclose(inFile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post `loadArray()`?

Comment: Done. Added just below my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `*count` is the number of elements in `array` (used and unused) then this

```
        array[*count+1] = array[*count];
```

will go beyond the boundaries of `array`. The `array` may be index from 0 to *count - 1.

If `*count` is the number of used elements in `array`, you need to look at the total size of `array` before extending.

There are other indexes of `array` that could be >= *count as well. Look at them all carefully.

If array is malloc'ed in the code that calls `insertWord` you will need to `realloc` it to resize `array`.

In any event, seeing how array is created in the code that calls insertWord is needed to comment intelligently.

---

Ok, new info. Consider the situation where capacity=100, and count=99, you call insertWord and need to append the new word. This

```
array[*count+1] = array[*count];
```

becomes

```
array[100] = array[99];
```

That index of 100 is too big; capacity is 100, valid indices are 0-99. 
You can fix this by changing

```
if (*count >= *capacity) // double array
```

to

```
if (*count >= *capacity-1) // double array
```

Comment: I'll add the loadArray() function to my post right now.  As for the array[*(count+1)] = array[count];   -- This is because when shifting words to the right with array[I] = array[I-1] I would be overwriting the last element, this is what I thought of to replace the last element at the end, if you know of a better way to do that please feel free to share :)).  The loadArray() function takes care of the reallocation as you'll see in my post.

Comment: And to confirm, count IS the number of elements.

Comment: @Riptyde4, see my edit of the answer starting at "Ok, new info."

Comment: That did it.  Hm...who knew it was in my double array call all along.